# Why doesn't monodevelop install mongodriver via NuGet?

Tags: c#, nuget, monodevelop

When I create a console project in MonoDevelop and try to add a package via NuGet, my application stops and shows this error:

> ```
> Adding 'MongoDB.Bson 2.1.0' to NugetEx.
> Could not install package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not install package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.ExtractPackageFilesToProject (IPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReferenceToProject (IPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute (NuGet.PackageOperation operation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute (IPackage package, IPackageOperationResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference (IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference (System.String packageId, NuGet.SemanticVersion version, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.SharpDevelopPackageManager.AddPackageReference (IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.SharpDevelopPackageManager.InstallPackage (IPackage package, ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction installAction) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageManagementProject.InstallPackage (IPackage package, ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction installAction) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction.ExecuteCore () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.ProcessPackageAction.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageActionRunner.Run (IPackageAction action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.InstallPackage (IEnumerable`1 packageOperations) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.InstallPackage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.TryInstallingPackage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
> ```

Comment: Is this part of a larger package, like the MongoDb driver?

Comment: you must install driver for work with mongoDB(this tells in doc).

Comment: Are you installing the entire driver, or are you just trying to install this dependency package?

Comment: Look at the [.Net compatibility](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) ranges. You're targeting .Net4, so you have to use the old version 1.10. The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: i try to download  dependency package

Comment: I agree with Pierre-Luc Pineault but how to fixed this problem. I ask this stupid question because i never done this before

Comment: Hm looks like there's no NuGet support for the previous versions of MongoDB.Bson, they start at 2.0.0. You might have to search a bit or upgrade your .Net verison.

Answer (score 2):

Read that part of the error message:

> Could not install package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.1.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'

If we take a look at the [official driver page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/), we can confirm that Mongo 2.1.0 and .Net4 are indeed not compatible :

> [image: Mongo driver compatibility table]

As stated in the table above, you should install the version 1.10 instead.

However, that version does not seem to be available on NuGet. You will have to do a manual download on their [GitHub page for version 1.10](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases/tag/v1.10.0)

---

The way I verified if the version was available on NuGet, was with the following command:

```
Get-Package Mongo.BSon -ListAvailable -AllVersions
```

If it had been available, you could have used the following to install a specific version:

```
Install-Package Mongo.BSon -Version 1.10
```